# SQLAlchemy with single table inheritance expunge error

Tags: python, inheritance, sqlalchemy

I'm having an issue with python SQLAlchemy single table inheritance.

Model:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    userID = Column(String(64), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(64))
    type = Column('type', String(50))
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on': type}

class PasswordUser(User):
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'puser'}
    password = Column(String(64))

    def validatePassword(self, password):
        return (self.password == password)
```

In userManger.py I have this:

```
def userGet(userID):
    with DBStore.Session(db) as sess:
        user = sess.query(User).filter(User.userID==userID).one()
        sess.expunge(user)
    return user
```

In a test main method:

```
myUser = userManager.userGet('123')
myUser.validatePassword("password321')
```

This produces an error:

> sqlalchemy.orm.exc.DetachedInstanceError: Instance is not bound to a Session; attribute refresh operation cannot proceed

I have verified that myUser is of type 'PasswordUser', and it calls the correct 'validatePassword' method.

The stranger thing is that when I step through the code slowly (PyDev), it works without error.

It also works if my userGet method does a sess.query(PasswordUser).  But I want this method to be generic so it can return any type of 'User'.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that when you query just for `User`, **only** the attributes/columns for the User (base) class are queried from the database. In order to load also other columns (like `password`) for sub-classes, you need to instruct `query` to do so. You can do this by using [`with_polymorphic`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/inheritance.html#with-polymorphic), in which case your code might look like:

```
def userGet(userID):
    with DBStore.Session(db) as sess:
        user = sess.query(User).with_polymorphic('*').filter(User.userID==userID).one()
        sess.expunge(user)
    return user
```

If you do not do that, the sqlalchemy will try to load the missing attribute (in your case, `password`) automatically using the session, and this is why it complains that it cannot work with detached object.